# Cannot connect to MySQL db only on one machine

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-runtime

I am using the [MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) to send and receive data to a MySQL database in a Windows 8 Store app.  It works perfectly one one machine, but not on another.

Here is the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.RT.DLL
>   A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.RT.DLL
>   A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.RT.DLL
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
>      at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.OpenConnection()
>      at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Open()
>      at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
>      at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>      at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>      at QuantiView.Classes.clsGlobal.mMySqlConnect()
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.RT.DLL
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at QuantiView.Classes.clsGlobal.d_*20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at QuantiView.Pages.p1Project.d*_f.MoveNext()

And the connection code:

```
public static void mMySqlConnect()
{
   Debug.WriteLine("mMySqlConnect");
   Debug.WriteLine("internet = " + IsInternet());
   if (connection.Equals(null)) connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
   try
   {
      if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) connection.Open();
   }
   catch (MySqlException ex)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      switch (ex.Number)
      {
         case 0:
            Debug.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
            break;

         case 1045:
            Debug.WriteLine("Invalid username/password, please try again");
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

The two machines are both running Win8.1 fully updated, the same version of VS (2013 also updated), have the same references and installed assemblies, are connected to the same network.

Comment: Check this [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69760).

Comment: did you check firewall settings of both machines? are the firewall settings on both machine are identical?

Comment: The link with the workaround was helpful Brian, but it is written for winforms, WPF, web apps in that it suggests altering web.config, app.config, or machine.config ... none of which are used in windows 8 store apps.

Comment: This is the suggested workaround...As stated above the workaround is to adding to the *.config file of your app this line inside 

<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
  </system.data>
</DbProviderFactories>

Answer (score 0):

Open your **Package.appxmanifest** open **Capabilities** Tab and **Check Private Networks(Client & Server)**